Drama movie (late 80s/early 90s) about medical students reuniting after she learns she has a brain tumor
Girl and a boy meet at the university where they are both medical students. the boy is a musician too (a pianist) and they fall in love. The girl is very rich and we learn that her father is a lawyer. He don't agree with her relationship with the poor boy but when they finished their studies they leave together for the Red Cross in Africa. 
Something happens and the girl came back. She marries the lawyer that her father chose and the boy marries another girl who was in love with him for years (a cellist)
Many years later (they both have families) now, the female protagonist learns that she has brain tumor. He becomes her doctor and they become lovers again, for a while.
At the end of the movie, she dies and the movie ends with him playing the piano and his wife (who understand his pain) playing the cello.
